# Select–String : The term 'Select–String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: sql-server, powershell-4.0

I am trying to uninstall sql server 2016 instance completely in windows 8.1 pro and I am getting this select-string error. Here is the code:

```
    `$a = c:\temp\msiinv.exe -s | Select–String "SQL Server" -Context 1,1;
     $a = $a -replace "Product code:    ","msiexec /x """;
     $a = $a -replace ">", "rem";
     $a = $a -replace "\t", "";
     $a = $a -replace "}","}""";
     $a | Out-File c:\temp\remove.bat -encoding ascii;`
```

I had previously installed and uninstalled the server instance twice because of improper setup and now I wish to completely remove it from my machine. Check the below ss-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JymJN.jpg)
P.S. I am using the latest version of WindowsPS with .netfw v4.8

Comment: If I only execute the first line in this script then I get the Unknown Error: 1605(), which is for something that's not present but we are trying to uninstall it anyway. But that's not the case here as all my SQL components are installed with the server instance.

Comment: It's available on PS 5.1 and upwards only. But that came out in 2016, why do you not have it yet?

Comment: @Charlieface I am using the PS version: 5.1.14409.1005.